# Copy and paste multiple cells without overwriting existing cells EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for a bit of guidance.

I am trying to copy all cells from 4 worksheets into a master sheet.

I can copy one sheet of data to the master sheet but when i copy a second sheet it will overwrite the information previously copied to the master sheet.

This is the code that i am currently using to copy the data.

```
Sub Create_Master ()

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:P")
    Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Columns("A:P")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End sub
```

Any Thoughts?

Cheers Adam

Comment: loop through each cell, check if this cell already has information on master sheet, and if not, copy it

Comment: How do you want all the data to be arranged on the Master sheet?  If you want to paste each set under the previous one then you need to figure out how to copy only the range with data: you can't copy whole columns.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for getting back to me the way the date will need to be shown is as follows.  if each of the four sheets contains 15 rows of data ranging from columns A:P the first set of data will be displayed from A1:P15, the second from A:16:P31 - and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you ...

`Sub Create_Master ()`

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim sourceRows As Integer

Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

sourceRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourceSheet.Range("A:A"))

Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A1:P" & sourceRows)

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim targetRows As Integer

Set targetSheet = Worksheets("Master Sheet")

targetRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A"))

Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetRows + 1 & ":P" & targetRows + 1 + sourceRows)

sourceRange.Copy Destination:=targetRange
```

End Sub

It's using the worksheet function "CountA" to work out how may rows are in use, assuming that column A cells are always populated and that you don't have any data in that column below the stuff you want to copy. If you have column headings on the source sheet and the master then they'll get duplicated. So you might want to make the sourceRange start at A2.

HTH.